# Pasting text into Emacs 24 search command buffer

Tags: search, emacs24.4

I recently installed Emacs 24 on my Ubuntu machine. I access this machine via SSH from a Mac. I am trying to search for some text and I am pasting the text in the search command's buffer. I.e I do `C-s`, then paste by doing `⌘+v` on my mac keyboard.

The text gets pasted into the document instead of the search command's buffer.This wasn't the case with Emacs23 where the pasted text was in the search command and not in the document.

How do I get `⌘+v` to paste text into the search buffer?

Comment: Does a regular `C-y` not work? It works for me.

Comment: If `C-y` does not work, but it works if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q`, then recursively bisect your init file to find the culprit. You can use command `comment-region` to comment out a region of text (`C-u` to uncomment a region). Do that to narrow down your init file to 1/2 of it, then 1/4, 1/8, 1/16,...

Comment: @Drew, `C-y` and `⌘+v` do not run the same command in `isearch-mode`, in fact, C-y does not even run `yank`, the problem lies in the function `xterm-paste` (I think)

Answer (score 1):

In `emacs`, the keybindings for cut-and-paste are very different. This is an unfortunate fact, and it is very difficult to change. Anyway, it goes like this:

- `C-y` to "paste" (called `yank` in Emacs)
- `M-w` to "copy" (called `kill-ring-save` in Emacs)
- `C-w` to "cut" (called `kill-region` in Emacs)

Emacs has these commands because it existed long before `C-v` paste, `C-c` copy, and `C-x` cut became the norm. Emacs also has its own "clipboard" (called the `kill-ring`) which stores the things you cut.

Comment: Thanks, these work in the main buffer of the document but in the search command's buffer(minibuffer). I.e the place where I enter the search term after I do `C-s`.

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely that for you <kbd>⌘+v</kbd> is interpretted as  which runs the function `xterm-paste`. this function gets the text from your clipboard and then runs `yank` to insert it, however, in `isearch-mode` the normal yank keybinding actually runs a special command to yank into the isearch minibuffer instead of the current buffer.

My guess is that in the past, the minibuffer was actually active when isearching, and now it is not. I advised `xterm-paste` so them when run in `isearch-mode` it will act in a special way that works with `isearch` instead of just `yank`ing.

```lisp
(defadvice xterm-paste (around support-isearch-mode activate)
  (if isearch-mode
      ;; when isearch-mode, act special.
      (let* ((end-marker-length (length xterm-paste-ending-sequence))
             (pasted-text (with-temp-buffer
                            (set-buffer-multibyte nil)
                            (while (not (search-backward
                                         xterm-paste-ending-sequence
                                         (- (point) end-marker-length) t))
                              (let ((event (read-event
                                            nil nil
                                            ;; Use finite timeout to avoid                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                            ;; glomming the event onto                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                                            ;; this-command-keys.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                            most-positive-fixnum)))
                                (when (eql event ?\r)
                                  (setf event ?\n))
                                (insert event)))
                            (let ((last-coding-system-used))
                              (decode-coding-region
                               (point-min) (point)
                               (keyboard-coding-system) t)))))
        ;; then only real change
        (isearch-yank-string pasted-text))
    ad-do-it))
```

Look at the code from `xterm-paste` and you'll see that the special case in this adivce is just the copy and pasted code, expect `yank` has been changed to `(isearch-yank-string pasted-text))`

Comment: So do I change it back to `yank` ?

Comment: No, you just need to evaluate the code in the answer and normal OSX pasting should work.

Comment: When I eval the above region in Emacs 24.5, it does not cause `⌘+v` to start working.  Using `C-y` works, so maybe mapping `⌘+v` to whatever `C-y` is mapped to is the solution.